# Find the sides of a triangle given one side, the difference of two and one angle

Tags: trigonometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle such that $∠ACB=π/3$ and let a,b,c denote the lengths of the sides opposite to A,B,C respectively. We know that $a-b=3$ and $c=8$. How can I find the other two sides and angles?
I tried to solve it with the sine rule and the cosine rule but somehow something is always missing.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually enough information to solve the problem.  By the law of Cosines, $$a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\pi/3) = c^2 = 64,$$ which is equivalent to $a^2-ab+b^2 = 64$.  Since $a-b = 3$, $a^2-2ab+b^2 = 9$.  This means $ab = 64-9 = 55$.  So $$a^2+2ab+b^2 = (a^2-ab+b^2)+3ab = 64+3\cdot55 = 229,$$ which means $a+b = \sqrt{229}$.  We can now find $a,b$ from $a+b,a-b$: $$a,b = \dfrac{\sqrt{229}+3}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{229}-3}{2}.$$

Comment: But the answer in the textbook is a=7, b=4

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you both.

Comment: if $a = 7, b = 4, c= 8, C$ is very nearly a right angle (it is slightly obtuse), as $4, 7.5, 8.5$ is  a right triangle.

Answer (score 1):

@TanEma may be I can explain easier. So you just write cosine theorem first, than use data from your task and rewrite i according what you have [image]

After you solve equation you will get answer.

Comment: thank you, i appreciate it